# onHostDestroy() not called as documented

Tags: react-native

According to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/LifecycleEventListener.java

> 3. Navigating back from Activity A to a non-React Activity or to the home screen will trigger two events: onHostPause and onHostDestroy.

I have tried switching to the home screen from a React Activity, but only `onHostPause` is called. Shouldn't both `onHostPause` and `onHostDestroy` be called? Is this a bug?

I'm on react-native 0.51.

Comment: Seems like a documentation issue, as `Activity#onDestroy` isn't usually called when navigation away from it. See the [android activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: That's my understanding too. I thought it was weird how the doc emphasises on both being called after switching to home screen.

Comment: So is there an elegant way to pass Java module that the component was navigated away? Or the only solution is hacking it by passing a property on navigation from RN?

Answer (score 0):

For me `onHostDestroy` was called only when there is no debug session (React native packager, Metro server etc. not running, `npx react-native run-android` command was stopped). When debug session is on, onHostDestroy was not raised.

I'm on react-native 0.63.2.